# ASP.NET (Blazor Server) How to Export CSV File (CSV created by CsvHelper)

Tags: c#, csv, razor, blazor

I want to export a csv file, which are made by [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).

I searched already for a solution but to be honest i didnt get it.

This is my Code

```
private async Task GetExcel()
{
   var controller = new DownloadController();
   controller.DownloadFileMandantProvisioning(filteredResult)
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult DownloadFileMandantProvisioning(IEnumerable<ScopeMandantProvisioningModel> list)
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) { Delimiter = ";", Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, leaveOpen: true))
    {
         using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, config))
         {
               csv.WriteRecords(list);
         }
    }

     memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     return File(memoryStream, "text/csv", "MandantProvisioning.csv");
}
```

I dont unterstand at which moment the file should be downloaded? If i hit de button which calls the functionn nothing happens. I hope you can help me. Thank you very much :)

I tried something like [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1194665/How-to-Convert-a-List-Object-to-CSV-and-Download-C) but with CsvHelper.

I whatch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oIuKXIDZ9Pg) Video too, but didn't get it.

After Debugging i saw that i have a Read and Write Timeouts, but it didn't throw an exception or soemthing. Nothing happens.
[image: Failure]

Comment: Is there any error or is "nothing" happening?
Try debugging: 
Make the button do something completely different, like just writing something in the console or make an image appear.
And why not do it exactly as one of your examples?
You could also make it write something to the console every step of the way to make sure where its going wrong.

Comment: @RatzMouze Thank you. I updated my Question with a screenshot. I saw i have an read and write timeout.

Comment: Are you using blazor server or blazor webassembly?

Comment: @MarvinKlein Blazor Server.

Comment: Are the Blazor Server and the MVC Controller hosted in the same project? Or separate apps?

Comment: @mason they are in the same project i think

Comment: You think? Please verify. When things aren't working as expected, going off what you think will get you in trouble. You must verify your assumptions rather than assuming.

Comment: Assuming these are in the same app, then it doesn't make sense to create an instance of a controller in order to generate a file for Blazor Server. Instead, the logic for generating the file should be abstracted to a separate class, and your Blazor Server page can grab the file from that class, and provide it to the user.